# ToggleClass based on Image Height within li tag

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list created by wordpress.  each list item contains an image either portrait or landscape.  I would like the class of each list item to be defined based on the width or height of the image created within it. so if the image is 124px wide toggle class "landscape" and if it is 83px wide toggle class "portrait"

This seems pretty simple but I can't seem to get it figured out

it's for my prints page http://www.geoffpuryear.com/gp/prints/

Answer (score 1):

You can't re-use an ID like that, they have to be unique, so you should have `class="frame"` instead of `id="frame"`, and use a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to match:

```
jQuery$('div.frame').toggleClass(function() {
  return $(this).parent().is('#printviewer')) ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';
});
```

If `id="printviewer"` is repeated in the actual sample, make sure to change it to a class as well.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
$('li').toggleClass(function() {
    return $('img', this).width() == 124 ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';
});
```

Comment: Your current syntax would blow up...but also, you need to return something ;)

Comment: one other thing, this checks the width of the `<li>`, not the *attribute* width o the contained `<img>`...but the markup in the page matches none of the conditions, so I'm confused as to what the OP *really* wants here.